# Codeigniter 3 query builder auto quote wrongly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm am trying to get the sql format below

```
SELECT * FROM `ci_nest` WHERE `lft` > 9 AND `rgt` < 28 AND `rgt` = `lft` + 1 ORDER BY `lft`
```

However Codeigniter 3 is inserting the quotes at the wrong place.

My Code as follows

```
$this->db->where($leftcol . ' > ' . $leftval . ' AND ' . $rightcol . ' < ' . $rightval);
$this->db->where($rightcol . " = " . $leftcol . " +1");
$this->db->order_by($leftcol);
$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
```

What codeigniter query output is

```
SELECT *
FROM `ci_nest`
WHERE `lft` > 9 AND `rgt` < 28
AND `rgt` = `lft` `+1`
ORDER BY `lft`
```

As you can see at the line  and `rgt` = `lft` + 1 is being formatted wrongly by codeigniter 3 query builder.

Any workaround for this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: `$this->db->where($rightcol . " = " . $leftcol . '+1');`

Comment: Hey Nithin, if you got a solution please post it as a answer not comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the backticks by the optional 3rd parameter and create them by your own.

```
$this->db->where($rightcol, '`'.$leftcol.'`+1', FALSE);
```

Or with double quotes, seems better.

```
$this->db->where($rightcol, "`$leftcol`+1", FALSE);
```

Comment: Thanks , i forgot about the optional 3rd parameter

Answer (score 0):

For now a quick fix I found is to use Codeigniter 3 query method instead of the query builder.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `{$this->table_name}` WHERE 
`{$leftcol}` > {$leftval} AND `{$rightcol}` < {$rightval} AND
`{$rightcol}` = `{$leftcol}` + 1 ORDER BY `{$leftcol}`");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$this->db->where($leftcol . ' > ' . $leftval . ' AND ' . $rightcol . ' < ' . $rightval);
$this->db->where($rightcol . " = " . $leftcol + 1);
$this->db->order_by($leftcol);
$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
```

Comment: Query builder output is 
SELECT * FROM `ci_nest` WHERE `lft` > 22 AND `rgt` < 27 AND 1 IS NULL ORDER BY `lft` . The query being build is wrong but thanks for trying