# Set database schema in CodeIgniter for Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, schema

I'm trying to learn CodeIgniter and just getting my hands dirty with the `model` component of the MVC architecture.

I first tried using the query builder but found that it keeps adding quotes to my table/column names. A way to fix that is to use all caps on them and that fixed it. I hate writing in all caps though so I decided to just not use the query builder and do `$this->db->query();` instead.

The issue I have with this right now is that I have to constantly write the schema with the table name: `SELECT * FROM schema.table_name`. I would like to avoid having to write `schema.` for all tables I need to reference.

I browsed the documentation and saw [a configuration for setting schemas](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html#explanation-of-values) however it seems like it's only used with PostgreSQL and ODBC drivers. I still tried it but of course it didn't work as I expected. I still get an error saying the table could not be found.

**NOTES:**

I am logged in as my user but I need to run queries as a different user - i.e. logged in as `user1` but need to run queries as `user2.table_name`.

Comment: @ no backticks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31111046/2275490

Comment: @ schema: documentation of CI 3.0 says: `The database schema, defaults to ‘public’. Used by PostgreSQL and ODBC drivers.`

Comment: @Vickel I already solved the problem with quotes by doing `$db['default']['_protect_identifiers'] = false;`. Do you know of a way to avoid needing to constantly supply the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by adding a `__construct()` on my model class.

```
class My_model extends CI_Model {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->db->query("ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = my_schema");
  }

  public function get_awesome_user() {
    $this->db->select("u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname");
    $this->db->from("sys_users u");
    $this->db->where("u.username", $this->input->post("username"));

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
  }
}
```